# How to Centralize Controls Horizontally in a Custom XML Ribbon

Tags: xml, ms-access-2010

inside a group, I added an editbox with label + a button, on the first line. below, I added 4 navigation buttons. what I need is to centralize those 4 navigation buttons horizontally, under the editbox and green button.

I've tried many ways. my last try was by putting one empty box before the 4 buttons and one empty box after, unsuccessfully. in this last try, what happens is that the 4 navigation buttons come first and then the empty boxes, as shown in the picture below.

[image]

I also would like to place all the controls (editbox and green button + 4 nav buttons) on the bottom of the ribbon.

I know that there's a post talking about the use of the attribute `boxStyle="horizontal"` but, I'm using this attribute, unsuccessfully.

code:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
  <ribbon startFromScratch="true">
    <tabs>
      <tab id="tab0" label="Controles">
        <group id="grp0" label="Navegação">
            <box id="box0" boxStyle="vertical">
                <box id="box2" boxStyle="horizontal">
                  <editBox id="ebx13" label="Ir para" screentip="Campo Ir Para..." supertip="Digite o número ID do documento desejado e aperte o Botão ao lado."/>
                  <button id="btn14" size="normal" screentip="Botão Ir Para..." supertip="Carrega a tela com o documento desejado." imageMso="AnimationStartDropdown"/>
                </box>
                
                
            
                <box id="box4" boxStyle="horizontal">
                    <box id="box5"> </box>
                    <box id="box1" boxStyle="horizontal">                 
                      <button id="btn0" size="normal" screentip="Botão Ir para o Primeiro Registro" supertip="Carrega a tela com o primeiro registro salvo." imageMso="RewindLong"/>
                      <button id="btn1" size="normal" screentip="Botão Ir para o Registro Anterior" supertip="Carrega a tela com o registro anterior ao atual." imageMso="CatalogMergeGoToPreviousRecord"/>
                      <button id="btn2" size="normal" screentip="Botão Ir para o Próximo Registro" supertip="Carrega a tela com o próximo registro ao atual." imageMso="CatalogMergeGoToNextRecord"/>
                      <button id="btn3" size="normal" screentip="Botão Ir para o último Registro" supertip="Carrega a tela com o último registro salvo." imageMso="FastForwardLong"/>                 
                    </box>
                    <box id="box6"> </box>
                </box>
                
                

            </box>
        </group>
        <group id="grp2" label="Registros">
            <box id="box3" boxStyle="horizontal">
              <button id="btn4" size="large" label="Novo" screentip="Botão Novo Registro" supertip="Cria um novo documento." imageMso="AddAccount"/>
              <button id="btn5" size="large" label="Duplicar" screentip="Botão Duplicar Registro" supertip="Cria um novo documento aproveitando os dados do documento carregado na tela. O ID desse novo documento será; novo." imageMso="AdpStoredProcedureQuerySelect"/>
              <button id="btn6" size="large" label="Editar" screentip="Botão Editar Registro" supertip="Altera os dados do documento carregado na tela." imageMso="IconPencilTool"/>
              <button id="btn7" size="large" label="Excluir" screentip="Botão Excluir Registro" supertip="Exclui o documento carregado na tela." imageMso="ChangeToDeclineInvitation"/>
            </box>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

some days ago I found a way to centralize controls horizontally. I did it by inserting a `<labelControl id="label1" label="   "/>` before the controls that I want to centralize and writing spaces in the label attribute as much as necessary to achieve the desired result.

```
    <box id="box2" boxStyle="horizontal">
        <labelControl id="label1" label="   "/>
        <box id="box3" boxStyle="horizontal">                 
          <button id="btn1" size="normal" screentip="Botão Ir para o Primeiro Registro" supertip="Carrega a tela com o primeiro registro salvo." imageMso="RewindLong"/>
          <button id="btn2" size="normal" screentip="Botão Ir para o Registro Anterior" supertip="Carrega a tela com o registro anterior ao atual." imageMso="CatalogMergeGoToPreviousRecord"/>
          <button id="btn3" size="normal" screentip="Botão Ir para o Próximo Registro" supertip="Carrega a tela com o próximo registro ao atual." imageMso="CatalogMergeGoToNextRecord"/>
          <button id="btn4" size="normal" screentip="Botão Ir para o último Registro" supertip="Carrega a tela com o último registro salvo." imageMso="FastForwardLong"/>                 
        </box>
    </box>
```

the result is as shown on the below picture:

[image]

maybe there's a better way to get that.

thanks.